# Jest not finding all tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jestjs, package.json

Jest is not finding all of my test files. It is ignoring a directory. When I run npm run jest:watch my tests in **./server** and its subdirectories are tested but no tests are found in **./client**

### What I have tried

I have tried creating a generic test file and moving it around. I found it would work in the following circumstances.
I have also tried using a direct path to the file - which didn't work.

### Possible causes

I think it may be something to do with the unusual directory structure I have

```
./client
./server
```

as opposed to

```
./server.js
./other server files..
./client/...client files
```

or it may be die to me trying to run jest from the node.js app and also have it look at files in the client directory (which contains an app written in React) - I don't care about running tests on react components (only modules). Alternatively it could be something to do with jest in the client directory messing things up.

| filename | ./server/middleware | ./ | ./client |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| delete.test.js | found by jest | found by jest | not found |

### My setup

my folder structure looks like this

```
./
./client  (react client app)
./client/package.json
./client/node_modules
package.json
node.modules
./server   (node.js api app)
./server/package.json
```

my jest is running from the ./package.json file.

### Other things I have tried

I have tried using direct paths for my file the below code works

```
"testMatch": ["<rootDir>/server/delete.test.js"],
```

but this code (in the folder I want) does not

```
        "testMatch": ["<rootDir>/client/delete.test.js"],
```

## code setup

### ./package.json

```
{
    "name": "Infoshot",
    "version": "0.0.4",
    "description": "Research Tool",
    "main": "cd ./server && server.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "cd ./server && node server.js",
        "server": "cd ./server && nodemon server.js",
        "client": "npm start --prefix ./client/",
        "clientinstall": "npm install --prefix client",
        "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\"  \"npm run client\"",
        "heroku-postbuild": "cd ./client && NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install  && CI= npm run build",
        "compile-saas": "node-sass ./client/src/scss/a_main.scss ./server/nodeClient/public/css/main.css -w",
        "test": "jest",
        "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch"
    },
    "jest": {
        "testEnvironment": "node",
        "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
            "./node_modules"
        ]
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.21.0",
        "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
        "config": "^3.2.2",
        "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
        "ejs": "^3.1.5",
        "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "express-validator": "^6.2.0",
        "ijavascript": "^5.2.0",
        "jest": "^26.6.3",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
        "mongoose": "^5.7.0",
        "nodemailer": "^6.4.14",
        "nodemailer-sendgrid": "^1.0.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "concurrently": "^4.1.2",
        "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
        "nodemon": "^1.19.2"
    }
}
```

### delete.test.json

```
describe.only('DELETE TEST: getDocument', () => {
    test('Say Hi', async () => {
        const bum = 'bum';
        expect(bum).toBe(bum);
    });
});
```

### ./client/package.json

As I said earlier I don't think this is relavant as it is not be run as I am running jest from ./server with npm run jest:watch

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "config": "^3.3.2",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.3",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.4",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.3.0",
    "serve": "^11.3.2",
    "styled-components": "^5.1.1",
    "uuid": "^3.3.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "previewProd": "react-scripts build && serve"
  },
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/components/documentEditor/*.js",
      "<rootDir>/server/",
      "!<rootDir>/node_modules/",
      "!<rootDir>/src/index.js",
      "!<rootDir>/src/registerServiceWorker.js"
    ]
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/react": "^10.4.9"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I found that if I removed all the mentions of jest in the ./client/package.json and also replaced the ./package.json with

```
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
            "**/*.{js,jsx}",
            "!**/node_modules/**"
        ]
```

it worked.

Comment: This might be better as an edit to the question and not as an asnwer

Comment: the `collectCoverageFrom` won't worked for me, but my issue was that I mentioned the containing folder name inside `testPathIgnorePatterns:[ /libs/, ... ]` in confusion, that to ignore  directory libs in project root, but the directory was also available inside `<rootDir>/src/` hence It was getting ignored, once I removed `/libs/` from the ignore patterns, Jest was able to tests all files mentioned in anywhere in hierarchy, hope it would help many onces.